# React: pass value from parent to child does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to pass a value`index` from parent to child. Both parent and child need have function to revise `index`. When parent revise `index`, child can not get the update. is there anything I can fix it?

parent class:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        index: 0
    }
}
        parentFunction(dir) {
            this.setState({
                index: 10
            });
        }
    render() {
      return(
         <Child index={this.state.index}/>
    );}
```

childclass:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            index: this.props.index
        };
    }
childFunction(dir) {
    this.setState({
        index: this.props.index+1     
    });
}
render() {
  return(
     <div>{this.state.index}</div>
);}
```

Comment: Instead of `this.props.index` in the child class, how about `props.index` instead?

Comment: nope.this is not the problem

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's at least _part_ of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to keep the updater function in both the class. You can pass the updater function from parent down to child and let the parent handle the state updates. Also setting a state based on props in constructor is an anti-pattern. You should use the prop in child directly for your usecase. In case you need to update the child state from props make sure to do that in the `componentWillReceiveProps` as well, since the `constructor` is only called the first time and the `componentWillReceiveProps` on every parent re-render

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.index!== this.props.index) {
            this.setState({
              index:newProps.index
            })
        }
    }
```

However what you need is

parent class:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        index: 0
    }
}
        parentFunction(dir) {
            this.setState({
                index: 10
            });
        }
     updaterFunction(dir) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
           index: prevState.index+1     
        }));
    }
    render() {
      return(
         <Child updaterFunction={(val) => this.updaterFunction(val)} index={this.state.index}/>
    );}
```

childclass:

```
updateProps = () => {
    this.props.updaterFunction();
}
render() {
  return(
     <div>{this.props.index}</div>
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the article about the lifecycle of react [react life cycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) then u will understand why,you pass the value from the parent to the children,but you didn't tell the react the it should be updated,add the code like beblow:

```js
//add this life cycle in the child component

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.index!== this.props.index) {
            this.setState({
              index:newProps.index
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) 2 options.

1. The best way to do this is to pass the parent function that changes
   the index to the child via props. Then you can call that function in
   the child class and it will change the parents state. In the render
   method of the child class just use the index from props rather than
   local state of the child.
2. The bad way to do this would be in the render method of child to
       have a call to set state that sets state of index equal to the value
       passed in props.

Comment: note that thomas's solution will also work but it may be suboptimal to store the same state in two classes